# How can I install a program, so that I can completely uninstall it later?

Tags: windows, memory

For university I need to install some programs for which I know, I will uninstall them after half a year.

From the past I know that simply uninstalling a program on Windows does not reset to the state before the installation. There are still some folders, icons, etc. which are related to the application, which are not deleted. Since my laptop has very little memory, I really want to avoid that.

What can I do in advance so I can get back to my current state later?
Can I somehow tell my PC that I want a specific program to be cleand clearly in advance? I was thinking about a virtual machine or something that I then can just kill when I dont need the program any more. But my PC  is a bit too slow for that.

Any idears?

and please excuse my bad english :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Even a "perfect" uninstaller will leave some registry entries behind. These are cache and tracking entries made by Explorer and their size is negligible.

If you want to attempt to cleanly uninstall you must keep track of the changes made to the system.

Stop all other running programs. Use a tool like [RegShot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) or [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) to take a snapshot. Then install **and** run and then exit the installed application. Now take the 2nd registry snapshot. To track installed files you can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

After uninstalling you would then manually inspect the system to make sure all traces are gone by comparing with the install logs you made. Keep in mind that some 3rd-party libraries (VC run-time, .net) might have to stay behind if other applications you installed later require them.

You could look at some of the 3rd-party uninstall applications, some of them claim to track and/or perform cleanup.

CCleaner and other such tools might also help.

A file just sitting there on your hard-disk does not use memory. Registry entries do however have a memory impact.

Comment: I dont know why you got a negativ rating for your answer, I'm glad you answered and you helped me with that. I'm sorry, that you got a bad raiting for that. Unfortunately, I cannot give you a posiive raiting, stackoverflow dont let me.

Comment: @Sandmann Your question is not really a programming question and some people consider it bad form to answer those I suppose. Please ask on Super User next time...

Comment: You are cool :)